# Add all my text in one cell of the table and being able to see the other columns

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to have a table with three columns. The first column have a long text and the others have short. I am using below code:
but the text in first column cannot be seen well and the other columns disappeared as in the figure. Please help me. Thanks

```
\tabcolsep=0.11cm
\begin{table*}
    \newcommand{\tabincell}[2]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
    \caption{SegNet Performance with Different Optimizers.}

    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
        \tabincell{c}{Text Message} & \tabincell{c}{Video Number} & \tabincell{c}{State}\\\hline
        part of the Semantic feature have proved to be a very good
        feature if the little effort in making paraphrases in the corpus
        can be done. & \tabincell{c}{74} & \tabincell{c}{craving}\\\hline
        Computer Science is a specialized domain, and so any or-
        dinary paraphrases generation cannot be easily used here
        unless there is a human effort be involving in marking the
        words that can be permuted from the original to form true or
accurate paraphrases & \tabincell{c}{0.8219} & \tabincell{c}{0.8014} \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\vspace{0.25 cm}
\label{tab2.Spec}
\end{table*}
```

[image: !!]

Comment: You could try a column of fixed width, e.g. `p{7.5cm}` instead of `c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tabularx` and set the first column header to `X`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\begin{document}

\tabcolsep=0.11cm
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{SegNet Performance with Different Optimizers.}
    \smallskip

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|c|c|}\hline
        Text Message & Video Number & State \\ \hline
        part of the Semantic feature have proved to be a very good
        feature if the little effort in making paraphrases in the corpus
        can be done. & 74 & craving  \\ \hline
        Computer Science is a specialized domain, and so any or-
        dinary paraphrases generation cannot be easily used here
        unless there is a human effort be involving in marking the
        words that can be permuted from the original to form true or
accurate paraphrases & 0.8219 & 0.8014 \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\label{tab2.Spec}
\end{table}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked as I wanted and you saved me a big time!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which (a) is very similar to the one given in [@AboAmmar's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467979/5001), in that it uses a `tabularx` environment and the `X` column type for the first column, and (b) gives the table a more open "look" by omitting all vertical rules and employing fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules.

Note that all `\tabincell` "wrapper" directives may be omitted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
%\tabcolsep=0.11cm  % is this really needed?
\caption{SegNet Performance with Different Optimizers.}
\label{tab2.Spec}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Xcc@{}}
\toprule
Text Message & Video Number & State\\
\midrule
Part of the Semantic feature have proved to be a very good feature if the little effort in making paraphrases in the corpus can be done. 
& 74 & craving\\
\addlinespace
Computer Science is a specialized domain, and so any ordinary paraphrases generation cannot be easily used here unless there is a human effort be involving in marking the words that can be permuted from the original to form true or accurate paraphrases. 
& 0.8219 & 0.8014 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```